# Java - Scanner with multiple delimiters

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I would like to use a Scanner to read input (a number) until it encounters either '+','-',
'*', or '/'.  These operators should end the input, and the value before the respective operator should be stored in a variable.

I am thinking about doing this by using the operators as delimiters.  Am I on the right track, or is there a better way to do this?

Nik

Answer (score 2):

`String.split( )` is probably your best bet here.

But be careful! `String.split()` takes a [Regular Expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) as its argument. Because `+` and `*` are meta-characters with special meaning in regular expressions, you need to escape them.

The regular expression `"-|\\+|\\*|/"` will split your string on occurrences of `-` or `+` or `*` or `/`.

This example code should print the following: `[20, 30, 40]`

```
String test = "20+30*40";

String[] tokens = split( "-|\\+|\\*|/" );

System.out.println( Arrays.toString( tokens ) )
```

Comment: @Kevin glad we could help! If your question was answered, remember to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer which was most useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

you can use the String.split() function to split a string of characters by either +, - , or /.

which will end up being

```
String[] allStrings = String.split("+|-|/");
```

Which gives you an array of Strings that were split by either of those delimiters.

If you need more help, please post your code so we can help you.

Have a good day